# responsive 2 columns don't line up at top

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like to create a simple 2-column responsive page - no footer or header, just the columns.  When I use the below code, the right column starts below and to the right of the first column. Surely I am missing something simple - not a tough thing for being pretty new to responsive design. (BTW, the columns will differ much in length than in this sample.)

CODE:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.lcol {
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 33%;
  top: 0;
}
.rcol {
  float: right;
  padding: 1%;
  width: 65%;
  top: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .lcol,
  .rcol {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="lcol">
    ---contentLEFT--- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </div>

  <div class="rcol">
    ---contentRIGHT--- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: did you see my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your are not summing the `width` + `padding` correctly, therefore overflowing, it should be no more than `100%`

You can use [`box-sizing:border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) so the `padding` and the `border` won't interfere in the calculations,

> **border-box**
>
> The `width` and `height` properties include the content, the `padding` and `border`, but not the `margin`. This is the box model used by Internet
>   Explorer when the document is in Quirks mode. Note that `padding` and
>   `border` will be inside of the box e.g.  `.box {width: 350px; border:`
>   `10px solid black;}` leads to a box rendered in the browser of `width:`
>   `350px.` The content box can't be negative and is floored to 0, making
>   it impossible to use `border-box` to make the element disappear.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
.container {
  max-width: 100%
}
.container > div {
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
.lcol {
  width: 35%;
  background: lightgreen
}
.rcol {
  width: 65%;
  background: lightyellow
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .lcol,
  .rcol {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="lcol">
    ---contentLEFT--- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </div>

  <div class="rcol">
    ---contentRIGHT--- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: THANKS! Forgot the padding would be on both sides!

Comment: I still need to get to 15 before I can publicly accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.left{
  background-color:red;
  height:50vh;
}
.right{
  background-color:green;
  height:50vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 left">
    This is the left column.
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9 col-xs-9 right">
    This is the right column.
  </div>
</div>
```

Since you are new to the responsive design, I would suggest you to use Bootstrap. It is very easy to manage alignments using the column method that it provides. You can either download Bootstrap from here.  http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ 
Or use this CDN in the head tag of ur html file.
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

You can also learn the basics from www.w3schools.com.

This is the code that I've modified(using bootstrap)..